# ggplot histogram color gradient

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to visualize the diamonds data from ggplot2 in a histogram where I show the distribution of carats.

I've tried to move the aes values from ggplot to geom_histogram(), to try ..fill.., and to manipulate the code in different ways but the result is the same.

```
histogram<- ggplot(diamonds, aes(x=carat, fill=carat)) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.1) + scale_fill_gradient(low='blue', high='yellow')
```

I would expect to see my histogram go from blue to yellow as the carats increase but I still see it in grey.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try with `fill=..x..`:

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(x=carat, fill=..x..)) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.1) + scale_fill_gradient(low='blue', high='yellow')
```

[image: histogram with color gradient]

Comment: Thanks! I think I got confused by the documentation and other questions I read, so when I saw ..x.. I thought I need to replace the x with my x.